# Find a Function in Web-Page

Tags: javascript

The price in this web-page updates all the time:
https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/ESM20/overview

How can I find the JS-functions that gather that number, so that I can call it from the Chrome developer console?

Comment: You can set a DOM breakpoint on it. In Chrome DevTools: Right-click the element whose contents change and select "Break on" => "Subtree modifications"

Comment: If you then notice your breakpoint never fires, but the element still changes, then maybe the element is _replaced_, in which case you need to find the parent element that stays static and attach the subtree modifications breakpoint there, or attach a "Node removal" breakpoint to the child that is getting replaced (but then you'd have to do that every time again when it changed)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

- Inspect the price changing element.
- Look for the Id.
- Now search for that Id in the elements tab of the developer tool and find the function updating it.

Comment: It may not be referenced by ID or class or anything like that though, the JS code which created it may keep a direct reference to it, and/or it may be part of a virtual DOM like React's. Then this method wouldn't work.